# How can I eliminate delay with Globe key when switching input sources on MacBook?

Tags: macos, keyboard, input-source

When I switch input sources with globe key on my `MacBook Pro 2021` with `macOS 12.0.1` it actually doesn't change anything until this little pop-up window disappears.
[image]

It's really annoying to wait when you constantly switch languages while typing. Also I noticed that switching with Control+Space doesn't produce any delay.[image]

Is there a way to switch input sources without delay with globe key, just like with Control+Space? Currently I'm using [Karabiner](https://karabiner-elements.pqrs.org) to map globe key to Control+Space but this approach kills fn modifier functionality so I'm looking for more appropriate way to solve this problem.

Comment: You can use Caps Lock to switch between Latin and Russian, and that might be faster.

Comment: @TomGewecke Yeah, but the question was
"Is there a way to switch input sources without delay with globe key, just like with Control+Space", so it's not a solution :/

Comment: Does Caps Lock give you the same kind of delay as Globe Key does then?

Comment: No, Caps Lock works fine.

Comment: There is similar question I've answered [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/457571/491752)