# CAPS LOCK has to be double-tapped

Tags: macos, caps-lock, sonoma

I recently upgraded my Macbook Pro to Sonoma.  Since then, my CAPS LOCK key has been acting strangely.  I can only turn it on/off by double-tapping it.  Otherwise, it behaves exactly like the Shift key.  That is, I have to hold it down to get uppercase characters.

How can I diagnose/fix this issue?

Comment: The caps lock delay has a lot of discussions. https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/386841/5472 and https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/440928/5472 and https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/81234/5472 have some relevant info in case the double tap is bypassing the intentional short delay on that key.

Comment: @bmike, I'm not experiencing any delay.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turning "Full Keyboard Access" off in System Settings does the trick.